The location of the complex zeros of the "new" functions $\Xi_F(s)$ and $\Xi_L(s)$
Defining the $\boldsymbol{\Xi_F}$function as $$\Xi_F(s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{F_n^s}}$$ where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers, and the $\boldsymbol{\Xi_L}$function as $$\Xi_L(s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{L_n^s}}$$ where $L_n$ are the Lucas numbers, and by studying, from a numerical point of view, the location of their zeros in the complex plane up to $0<\Im(s)<200000$, I found that they are included in the strip $0 < \Re(s) < 0.705$ for the $\Xi_F(s)$ function, and $0 < \Re(s) < 0.936$ for the $\Xi_L(s)$ function.
More precisely, I found that:
$$
\begin{align}
0.704717 < \sigma_{\sup\!F} := \sup{\{\Re(s) : \Xi_F(s)=0\}}\\
0.935318 < \sigma_{\sup\!L} := \sup{\{\Re(s) : \Xi_L(s)=0\}}
\end{align}
$$
(See my document on the zeros of the $\Xi$-functions on the complex plane).
I was wondering if it could be demonstrated what the maximum value of $\Re(s)$ of the zeros of the two functions can be,
in other words, what are the values of $\sigma_{\sup\!F}$ and $\sigma_{\sup\!L}$. Thank you.
Notes

It may be interesting to compare the present question to my similar  earlier one (and associated answer) on the new Psi function $$\Psi(s) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac{1}{n!^s}}$$
MathOverflow, The location of the zeros of the "new" function Psi

I'd like to thank Prof. Elkies for his comment on the notation.


Referenes
[1] Roberto Trocchi, The $\Xi_F$ and $\Xi_L$ functions and their zeros on the complex plane, technical report.

The notations $\xi_F$ and $\xi_L$ are unfortunate because
$\xi$ is already used in analytic number theory for the
"completed $\zeta$ function" that has a $s \leftrightarrow 1-s$ symmetry.
Maybe $\Xi_F$ and $\Xi_L$, since you write "Xi_F" and "Xi_L" with a capital X?

December 30, 2024
In the case of Xi_L function:
with $s:=\sigma+i t$
$$\Xi_L(s) = 0$$
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{e^{-s\log(L_n)}}$$
taking real parts:
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{\Re(e^{-s\log(L_n)})}$$
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{e^{-\sigma\log(L_n)}\cos(-t\log(L_n))}$$
$$-1 = \sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{L_n^{-\sigma}\cos(t\log(L_n))}$$
defining the coefficients:
$$C_n(t) := \cos(t\log(L_n))$$
when
$$t(\log(L_n)-\log(L_{n-1})) = k_n(t) \pi$$
if $k_n(t)$ is an even integer then $C_n(t) = C_{n-1}(t)$
if $k_n(t)$ is an odd integer then $C_n(t) = -C_{n-1}(t)$
so:
$$k_n(t) := \frac{t(\log(L_n)-\log(L_{n-1}))}{\pi}$$
Now suppose there exists a $t$ (very large, and so will the $k_n(t)$ integers "degree of freedom") such that we can construct the coefficients $C_n(t)$ so as to have the extreme case of $\sigma$ (highest value).
Since $C_1(t) = +1$, to have the worst case of higher sigma, simply we would like all $C_n(t) = -1$ for $n\ge2$.
We will have $k_2(t)$ an odd integer, and $k_n(t)$ even integers for $n\ge3$.
But this in not possible as Prof. Noam D. Elkies' comment pointed out: "because the $F_n$ and $L_n$ that exceed 1 satisfy a few multiplicative relations that prevent the terms $1/F_n^s$ or $1/L_n^s$ from being simultaneously near -1."
So, since not all coefficients are simultaneously equal to -1, the rest of this answer was wrong. I edited it to at least calculate the upper bounds.
So, please, consider this answer as a comment.
So the answer to the question:
$$\sigma_{supL} := \sup{\{\Re(s) : \Xi_L(s)=0\}}$$
will be the solution to the equation:
$$-1=\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{L_n^{-\sigma}C_n(t)}$$
The problem now is that we don't know the $C_n(t)$ coefficients.
We can only calculate the upper bound
Numerically, solving the:
$$-1 = -L_2^{-\sigma}-L_3^{-\sigma}-L_4^{-\sigma}-L_5^{-\sigma}-\sum_{n=6}^{\infty }{L_n^{-\sigma}}$$
the upper bound is:
$$\sigma_{supL} \le 0.979208218285$$
In the case of Xi_F function the only difference is that $C_2(t) = +1$ and then we would like to have all coefficients $C_n(t) = -1$ for $n\ge3$.
So the answer to the question:
$$\sigma_{supF} := \sup{\{\Re(s) : \Xi_F(s)=0\}}$$
will be the solution to the equation:
$$-2=\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }{F_n^{-\sigma}C_n(t)}$$
The problem now is that we don't know the $C_n(t)$ coefficients.
We can only calculate the upper bound
Numerically, solving the:
$$-2 = -F_3^{-\sigma}-F_4^{-\sigma}-F_5^{-\sigma}-\sum_{n=6}^{\infty }{F_n^{-\sigma}}$$
the upper bound is:
$$\sigma_{supF} \le 0.757054949691$$
Octave script files
These Octave script files calculate the $\sigma_{supF}$ and $\sigma_{supL}$ upper bound values:
Xi_F___sigma_sup.m
Xi_F___f_opt_real.m
Xi_L___sigma_sup.m
Xi_L___f_opt_real.m

This is not quite right because the F_n and L_n that exceed 1 satisfy a few
multiplicative relations that prevent the terms $1/F_n^s$ or $1/L_n^s$ from
being simultaneously near -1.  For F_n, we're lucky that $2^3 = 8$ involves
an odd power, but unlucky with $144 = 2^4 3^2$.  For $L_n$ there's
$3^4 4 = 18^2$.
